# Presence of risc-v float instructions for the (rv64ima-lp64) soft float compilaton

Tags: assembly, compilation, cross-compiling, glibc, riscv

I compiled glibc 2.33 for risc-v 64-bit(rv64ima-lp64) using the riscv-gnu-toolchain.

The glibc was configured with following flags

```
./configure --host=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=${PREFIX} --disable-werror --enable-shared --enable-obsolete-rpc --with-headers=${KERNEL_HEADERS} --disable-multilib
```

And the riscv-gnu-toolchain was configured and compiled with *--with-arch=rv64ima* and *--with-abi=lp64*

But on doing `objdump -D ld.so` in elf directory of glibc build, I am getting floating point instructions i.e.

```
   83b2e:   317e                    fld ft2,504(sp)
   83b32:   0f00                    addi    s0,sp,912
   83b40:   0014f80f            0x14f80f
   83b4c:   0f10                    addi    a2,sp,912
   83b52:   7345                    lui t1,0xffff1
   83b5a:   0029990f            0x29990f
   83b62:   31d2                    fld ft3,304(sp)
   83b66:   0f20                    addi    s0,sp,920
   83b68:   00000d0f            0xd0f
   83b6c:   7645                    lui a2,0xffff1
   83b6e:   f209                    bnez    a2,83a70 <_end+0x60890>
   83b72:   2800                    fld fs0,16(s0)
   83b74:   0017a00f            0x17a00f
   83b80:   0f30                    addi    a2,sp,920
   83b86:   7945                    lui s2,0xffff1
   83b8c:   3800                    fld fs0,48(s0)
   83b8e:   0018b00f            0x18b00f
   83b96:   325f 0000 3140          0x31400000325f
   83ba0:   7b45                    lui s6,0xffff1
   83bae:   317e                    fld ft2,504(sp)
   83bc8:   04f20803            lb  a6,79(tp) # 4f <GLIBC_2.27+0x4f>
   83bd2:   a300                    fsd fs0,0(a4)
   83bf2:   000031c7            fmsub.s ft3,ft0,ft0,ft0,rup
   83bf6:   00015713            srli    a4,sp,0x0
   83bfa:   1300                    addi    s0,sp,416
   83bfc:   000004e7            jalr    s1,zero # 0 <GLIBC_2.27>
   83c0c:   a908                    fsd fa0,16(a0)
   83c10:   3b00                    fld fs0,48(a4)
   83c50:   3216                    fld ft4,352(sp)
   83c60:   31f80803            lb  a6,799(a6)
   83c6a:   3b00                    fld fs0,48(a4)
   83c80:   2208                    fld fa0,0(a2)
   83c8a:   325f 0000 6313          0x63130000325f
   83caa:   2b18                    fld fa4,16(a4)
```

I am expecting some clarification on this, as the binary should not contain any float instructions.

Thank you.